# Higcharts and Laravel5 integration

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using Higcharts and I receive this correctly.

```
public function usuariosPorPerfil(){
    $user_info = \DB::table('users')
                 ->select('role_id', \DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('role_id')
                 ->get();
    return response()->json(['userInfo' => $user_info ]);
}
```

With this I receive an array, but how I can append this result to following code?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Usuarios por pefil'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Usuarios por perfil',
            data: [
                ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                ['Shanghai', 23.7]

            ],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I use this plugin:

[PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer](https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer)

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => User::first(),
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return View::make('hello');
}
```

And retrieve your javascript variables in your view:

```
console.log(foo); // bar
console.log(user); // User Obj
console.log(age); // 29
```